# Installing dotfiles somewhere other than Home directory

Tags: macos, path, terminal, location, dotfiles

Hey I am trying to install these dotfiles https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles.

When I install, it automatically unpacks everything into my home directory via bootstrap.sh.

I do not want them unpacked here I need an alternative location, however when I change the location in the rsync command:

```
rsync --exclude ".git/" --exclude ".DS_Store" --exclude "bootstrap.sh" \
                --exclude "README.md" --exclude "LICENSE-MIT.txt" -av --no-perms . ~
        source ~/.bash_profile
```

The dotfiles do not apply because terminal does not default to the new `.bash_profile` because it is not in the Home directory.

I need to know how to point my terminal application the the new `.bash_profile` I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply source the new `.bash_profile` from the one in your home. Append

```
[ -f /path/to/rsynced/.bash_profile ] && . /path/to/rsynced/.bash_profile
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` (the `bash_profile` in your home). This will only work for the shell startup file, not with the other dotfiles.

Alternatively, you can create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /path/to/rsynced/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: The dotfiles still have not applied... could it be because there is all sorts of other stuff in the dotfiles repo and it is not linking correctly?

Comment: As a side not is it possible to install dotfiles into /usr/bin/ so they apply to all users?

Comment: make sure to restart your shell when you modify `.bash_profile`. And it could be that it refers to files it does not find. And also, all the dotfiles are not linked to `.bash_profile`. for instance `.vimrc` has nothing to do with it so you need to create a symlink for that one too

Comment: Ahhh I see so I have to essentially sym link it all into Home anyway.. Damn, is it possible to install into /usr/bin/ so it applies across all users?

Comment: `/usr/bin` is for binaries. Better put the startup files in `/etc/profile.d` or `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: It won't apply to all users simply by putting them in a centralized location. Each application will try and find them in the user's home anyway. One thing you can do is put them in `/etc/skel` so that they are copied to the home of the user when it is created with `adduser`

Comment: cd /etc/profile.d or /etc/bashrc do not exist, should I create them? will that work?
--Edit--
Never mind they are a file not directory

Comment: depends on your Linux distribution

Comment: Ok forget what I wrote about /etc/skel and /etc/profile.d then. I am afraid I can't help more